# Tomcat : Does it supports JSR 352

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7

Does tomcat ( any version ) supports JSR 352  ie java 7 batch framework ? I am using JBoss and its supporting ( written in documentation as well ). I have not found any documentation in which it is written that tomcat supports JSR 352.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes **Tomcat** 7.0 supports **JSR 352**. In fact any application server support JSR 352 and tomcat 7.0 is appliaction server so it can support JSR 352. 
for more details visit this [link](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2013/11/batch-processing-java-enterprise-edition-jsr-352-jee7-spring-batch/)

Comment: Your answer maybe right but supporting link should be from a reliable authority: blog links are not the best one.

Comment: @JunedAhsan you are right but i found that one thats why i put it here

Comment: It's important to note that Tomcat itself doesn't support JSR 352. The link provided actually just add Spring Batch implementation which is compatible with JSR 352. Tomcat is not a full blown application server, actually it's a lightweight servlet container you can extend using third party implementations.

Comment: I totally support @utluiz comment. This should not be the accepted answer as it is wrong on multiple levels.

Answer (score 1):

No, tomcat doesn't support JSR 352 natively, you have to use spring batch configured for run batch in jsr 352 style.